# Unable to to connect to repository SVN

Tags: linux, bash, svn, svn-hooks, pre-commit

I wrote a pre-commit hook that checks if trunk version.txt file is updated compared with version.txt in tag. 
When I run the script in console everything is fine, but when I try to commit I've got this

> Authentication realm: http://localhost:80 Subversion Repository
>   Password for 'www-data': svn: E070014: Unable to connect to a
>   repository at URL 'http://localhost/svn/myrepo2/tags'

And also this if --force-interactive is off

> svn: E215004: Authentication failed and interactive prompting is
>   disabled; see the --force-interactive option

I checked everything step-by-step and it seems like thats the line that causes the problem:

```
tag=$(svn list /some/path/tags --force-interactive | sort -n | tail -n 1 )
```

Is there any alternative to svn ls to check the latest tag or the files within folder tags?

```
#!/bin/bash  

#get latest tag
tag=$(svn ls  /some/path/tags --force-interactive | sort -n |  tail -n 1)

#get content of file from the latest tag
fileFromTag=$(svn cat /some/path/tags/$tag/version.txt)

#get content of file from trunk
file=$(svn cat some/path/trunk/version.txt)

#compare current file with file from latest tag
if [ "$fileFromTag" == "$file" ]
then
    echo "Update version.txt" 
    exit 1
fi
```

And here's the repository structure

```
 tags/
  1.1.0/
   version.txt
  1.1.3/
   version.txt
  1.1.5/
   version.txt
  1.1.6/
   version.txt
  1.2.0/
   version.txt
  rel_1.0/
   version.txt
 trunk/
   version.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that the `svn` client does not authenticate to the server and there are no cached credentials. But the main problem is the commands that you run in your hook script:

- Consider switching from `svn` command-line client to [`svnlook`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svnlook).
- If by some reason you have to use `svn` command-line client in hooks, use the file:// URLs instead of HTTP(S) URLs. The hook runs locally on the same computer with your repositories and the server, so it makes sense to access the repos directly.

Comment: Thanks, switching to svnlook helped.